# Comparing 8 - bit Unsigned Integer to HEX Failing

Tags: c++, hex, unsigned-integer

I have a C++ Vector full of uint8_t values from a TCP data segment. I am looking specifically for 1 of two values which should be at the first index of the vector.

I have the following if statement to express my logic.

```
if ( ui8BufferIn.at(0) != 0xE4 || ui8BufferIn.at(0) != 0xE2){
    printf("\nWe have a problem, no parsing will be done, Package Type = %u\n", ui8BufferIn.at(0));
    proceed = false;
}
```

The above if statement is executing when it shouldn't. I get the following printout:

```
We have a problem, no parsing will be done, Package Type = 226
```

So you don't have to do the math, `226` as an integer is `0xE2` in HEX.

I've been at this a while, so it very well may be something simple, but any help would be great!

Comment: I suspect you want && rather than ||.  As it is, your condition always evaluates true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want your logic to be:

```
if ( ui8BufferIn.at(0) != 0xE4 && ui8BufferIn.at(0) != 0xE2){
```

As right now you're saying "If either case of: (it's not `0xE4`) or case of: (it's not `0xE2`), we have a problem" - which, if I understand correctly, is not what you want to say. With your statement, you could be getting `0xE2`, but because you're not getting `0xE4` (`ui8BufferIn.at(0) != 0xE4`), your statement executes.

Answer (score 3):

The logic you have goes as such:

```
If (value is not (value a)) OR (value is not (value b)) then...
```

Lets' look at the possibilities:

```
Value = a: then value is not b: result is true
Value = b: then value is not a: result is true
Value = other: the value is not a: result is true
```

So the if statement always evaluates to true

Comment: Upvoted... I feel important to say that the statement is always true, as it cannot be both predicates false at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

There's a small logic error in your code. In this case, your error will always appear. Say the `uint8_t` value is `0xE2`. You will get the following condition:

```
if(0xE2 != 0xE4 || 0xE2 != 0xE2)
    //Error
```

Which will evaluate to:

```
if(true || false) //Actually the second operand will not be evaluated
    //Error
```

Which will execute your error condition. Actually for any given input, your error function will execute. Except if your `uint8_t` value manages to compare equal to both `0xE2` and `0xE4`, but for as far as I know, such a value currently does not exist.

The simplest solution would be to change your 'or' into an 'and', giving the following code:

```
if(ui8BufferIn.at(0) != 0xE4 && ui8BufferIn.at(0) != 0xE2)
    //Error
```